# how to get data from queue in cobol?

Tags: queue, cobol

I want to get data from queue in a cobol program in a way that the program listens to queue and wait for message,if queue is empty the program waits, once a message is coming to queue, it gets the message and stops listening to queue. I found out that MQGET function can do it. actually I found out I can listen to queue by changing MQGET options.but how can I set options to get what I want?

Also I'd like to know more about this function and how its work. how can I find its code?

Comment: [MQGET - Get message](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/7.5?topic=calls-mqget-get-message) - The MQGET call retrieves a message from a local queue that has been opened using the MQOPEN call.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Is MQGET a cobol built in function? If so, how can i find its code. This url just explain its parameters. I want to see its code.

Comment: Sorry, but IBM does not post the source code of internal programs.  The MQ routines could be written in assembler.

Comment: The MQ routines are a part of [IBM WebSphere MQ](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/7.5?topic=mq-about-websphere) IBM WebSphere MQ is an IBM proprietary product.

Comment: Thank you so much. How can I set MQGET options to get what i want. I want my program listen to queue to get a message, if there´s no message in queue wait there, once  it gets a message the program stop listening. After processing that message it comes to get another message from queue.

Comment: In CICS there is the feature for temporary storage queue. However, I don't think the code will get alerted when queue changes. Also, you need to think about how to compile your code so it stays alive....I don't think this possible in COBOL. Also a program resident in memory will cost so much...Think again if you really need this.

Comment: You really need to read the Webshere MQ manual. There is much more to it than just making an MQGET call, Its a rich and powerfull API  but you need to connect and set a few options, plus you will need to link to the MQ libraries and get permision to access the queue. IBM has a nice set of example programs here -- https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=examples-cobol

Comment: Thank you for comments. I found what i wanted here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/7.5?topic=queue-waiting-messages

Answer (score 0):

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. MQGET-PROGRAM.
DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01 MQ-HANDLER.
   05 MQ-HCONN           PIC S9(8) COMP VALUE 0.
   05 MQ-OD               PIC S9(8) COMP VALUE 0.
   05 MQ-MD               PIC X(10240).
   05 MQ-OPEN-OPTS       PIC S9(8) COMP VALUE 0.
   05 MQ-GET-OPTS        PIC S9(8) COMP VALUE 0.
   05 MQ-CI              PIC X(4) VALUE '    '.

01 MQ-QUEUE-NAME        PIC X(48) VALUE 'YOUR.QUEUE.NAME'.

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
MAIN-LOGIC.
   DISPLAY "MQGET Program is running..."

   EXEC CICS LINK PROGRAM('DFH0STAT') COMMAREA(MQ-HANDLER)
   IF MQ-HANDLER = DFH0STAT
   THEN
       MOVE MQ-HCONN TO MQ-HCONN OF MQ-HANDLER
   ELSE
       DISPLAY "Failed to initialize MQ connection"
       GOBACK
   END-IF

   EXEC CICS LINK PROGRAM('DFHM1STS') COMMAREA(MQ-HANDLER)
   IF MQ-HANDLER NOT = DFHM1STS
   THEN
       DISPLAY "Failed to connect to MQ queue"
       GOBACK
   END-IF

   MOVE 0 TO MQ-OPEN-OPTS
   EXEC CICS LINK PROGRAM('DFHM1OPE') COMMAREA(MQ-HANDLER)
   IF MQ-HANDLER NOT = DFHM1OPE
   THEN
       DISPLAY "Failed to open MQ queue"
       GOBACK
   END-IF

   MOVE 0 TO MQ-GET-OPTS
   MOVE MQ-QUEUE-NAME TO MQ-MD
   EXEC CICS LINK PROGRAM('DFHM1GET') COMMAREA(MQ-HANDLER)
   IF MQ-HANDLER NOT = DFHM1GET
   THEN
       DISPLAY "Failed to retrieve message from MQ queue"
   ELSE
       DISPLAY "Message received from MQ queue: "
       DISPLAY MQ-MD
   END-IF

   MOVE 0 TO MQ-OPEN-OPTS
   EXEC CICS LINK PROGRAM('DFHM1CLQ') COMMAREA(MQ-HANDLER)
   IF MQ-HANDLER NOT = DFHM1CLQ
   THEN
       DISPLAY "Failed to close MQ queue"
   END-IF

   EXEC CICS LINK PROGRAM('DFHM1DIS') COMMAREA(MQ-HANDLER)
   IF MQ-HANDLER NOT = DFHM1DIS
   THEN
       DISPLAY "Failed to disconnect from MQ queue"
   END-IF

   DISPLAY "MQGET Program finished."

   EXEC CICS RETURN

END PROGRAM MQGET-PROGRAM.
```

Please note that this program assumes that you are running it within a CICS environment, as it uses CICS commands to interact with IBM MQ. Make sure to replace 'YOUR.QUEUE.NAME' with the actual name of your queue. Additionally, you may need to modify the program to fit your specific COBOL compiler and environment.